# In R, for a cell that fulfills multiple string conditions

Tags: r, csv, if-statement

I am a bit new to R and I am using a sample dataset to get my hands dirty with using *ifelse* statements. In my Excel spreadsheet, there are numerical values assigned within cells to the category with the column heading "ethnicity" based upon how an individual self-identified. The ethnicity with corresponding code is as such:

```
1 - Asian
2 - Black or African American
3 - Hispanic or Latino
4 - Native American or American Indian
6 - Native Hawaiian or Pacific Islander
5 - Other (for those who identify with an ethnic group not listed)
7 - Caucasian
8 - Uncertain (for those who are unsure of their ethnicity or what ethnic group they identify with)
9 - Prefer not to answer (chose not to answer)
```

So, after loading in my file cleaned-demographic-raw_data.csv using `read.csv`, and assigning it to the variable name "DataAll_Analytical":

```
DataAll_Analytical <- read.csv(".../Qualtrics_Raw-Clean_2019/cleaned-demographic-raw_data.csv", header = T, na.strings=c("NA"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

My goal is to get a column with binary values based upon extracting the above numerical values as strings. A value of "1" for true is assigned for an individual that self-identified with a corresponding ethnic group or false "0" if they did not. My current approach is:

```
    #Started with 8 and 9 since those were easiest to account for
#returns 1 if the user does not know, 0 for false
    DataAll_Analytical$any_dont_know <- ifelse(is.na(str_extract(DataAll_Analytical,"8"))==T,0,1) 
#returns 1 if the user did not answer, 0 for false
    DataAll_Analytical$no_answer <- ifelse(is.na(str_extract(DataAll_Analytical,"9"))==T,0,1) 
# count for asian only     
    DataAll_Analytical$any_asian <- ifelse(is.na(str_extract(DataAll_Analytical$eth,"1"))==T,0,1) 
# count for black only
    DataAll_Analytical$any_black <- ifelse(is.na(str_extract(DataAll_Analytical$eth,"2"))==T,0,1)  
# count for hispanic only
    DataAll_Analytical$any_hispanic <- ifelse(is.na(str_extract(DataAll_Analytical$eth,"3"))==T,0,1) 
# count for native_american_only
    DataAll_Analytical$any_native_american <- ifelse(is.na(str_extract(DataAll_Analytical$eth,"4"))==T,0,1)
# count for others 
    DataAll_Analytical$any_other <- ifelse(is.na(str_extract(DataAll_Analytical$eth,"5"))==T,0,1)
# count for those who are only hawaiian/pacific islander 
    DataAll_Analytical$any_hawaiian_pacific<- ifelse(is.na(str_extract(DataAll_Analytical$eth,"6"))==T,0,1)
 # count for those who are only white 
    DataAll_Analytical$any_white<- ifelse(is.na(str_extract(DataAll_Analytical$eth,"7"))==T,0,1)
```

However, I want to account for individuals who identify as multiracial. That means an individual who  specified they are Black, Caucasian, and Asian would have the string combination "1,2,7" for that corresponding cell. In the case of individuals who identify as multiracial, I would like to count them as a separate group rather than overlapping with the other predefined ethnic groups.

I thought about using string extraction for this method as well in conjunction with if-else statements, but I am concerned about potential overlap or misidentification. Would there be an approach I could use to sort someone who is multiracial but identifies with Black as one of their ethnicities ("2","3","6") into a "multiracial" category while someone who identifies only as Black ("2") would get sorted into a group for those who identify only as Black?

**EDIT:** Hi all, I wanted to include a subset of the data I am working with. There were over 237 entries so I got this output from `dput(head(DataAll_Analytical, 20))`:

```
structure(list(eth = c("7", "7", "7", "2", "7", "7", "7", "5", 
"2,3,7", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "7", "7", "7", "2", "2"
)), .Names = "eth", row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

**EDIT 2:** As an example of output for the binary values, I have for participants who identified as black:

```
> DataAll_Analytical$any_black <- ifelse(is.na(str_extract(DataAll_Analytical$eth,"2"))==T,0,1) # count for black only 
> print(head(DataAll_Analytical$any_black, 10))
 [1] 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1
```

I chose the first ten results to demonstrate that the 9th element does contain a "2", but it also contains "3" and "7" (individual identifies as Black, Hispanic/Latino, and Caucasian). I would like to be a bit more exclusive here rather than having that individual grouped with those that identify only as Black.

Comment: Hi Road, in order for the community to help we need a minimum reproducible example to cut and paste into our R session so we can get your same error. You can provide a subset of your data using `dput`.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(DataAll_Analytical)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(DataAll_Analytical, 20))`.

Comment: Hi @mysteRious, could I provide a small subset using Pastebin?

Comment: just do `DataAll_Analytical %>% sample_frac(0.25) %>% dput() -> df` and copy the output it produces to your question text above... instead of 0.25 pick a percentage that will result in 10-20 rows of data. we can copy and paste into our R & will have a dataframe `df` containing your data

Comment: Hi All. I used @RuiBarradas, and the output that was generated was: `structure(list(eth = c("7", "7", "7", "2", "7", "7", "7", "5", 
"2,3,7", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "7", "7", "7", "2", "2"
)), .Names = "eth", row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: Hi Road, maybe you could group those who identify their selves as multi ethnic. If you assign those a number, you could keep working as you are doing with ``ifelse``. Give us reproducible example and we will help you. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make sure I'm reading your post correctly: I think you want to classify people by a given race/ethnicity if, and only if, they report *only* that race/ethnicity (and not multiple categories). If so, you're on the right track, but you don't need a `str_extract` -- just check whether the given entry is *equal* to something. For instance, your line

```
    DataAll_Analytical$any_black <- ifelse(is.na(str_extract(DataAll_Analytical$eth,"2"))==T,0,1)
```

has the effect of classifying observation 9 (reported race/eth `2, 3, 7`) as three different categories. To stop that from happening, try something like

```
DataAll_Analytical$any_black2 <- ifelse(DataAll_Analytical$eth == "2",1,0)
```

and similar replacements for the other lines. Note in particular that I switched the positions of the 1 and 0 on the `ifelse`. The logic is: scan the column, and check whether the contents are precisely "2" and nothing else. The `==` operator will have the effect of recording T and F values depending on whether the condition is met. You can verify that this column (called `any_black2`) will differ from the one you constructed only in observation 9. This is also a more straightforward way to write the code that will be easier to read and won't throw a warning message.

The question, then, is what to do with the multiracial / multiethnic entries. It sounds like you want to just make a new column to denote them; note that they are identified by having commas in their entries. To do something in the style that you started:

```
DataAll_Analytical$multi <- ifelse(is.na(str_extract(DataAll_Analytical$eth, ",")), 0, 1)
```

If you want to go more specific (i.e. have a column that designates a specific *way* a respondent is multiracial / mutliethnic), you can code it up in a similar fashion to the first thing I suggested.

Please let me know if you have questions or if I misread your intent.

Comment: Ahh, perfect. This was the one hill I needed to surmount before moving on! A combination of being a novice and overthinking the problem was my issue. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help! One more comment: even the `ifelse` in my solution is superfluous. If you just do `DataAll_Analytical$any_black2 <- (DataAll_Analytical$eth == "2") `, note that this will also do what you want, because the right side of `<-` will evaluate to a T/F vector which we can then record in our data frame. This will actually print the words `TRUE` and `FALSE`, which are coded in the background as 0 and 1 and can be converted to whatever you need without issue. (Just trying to give you another way to think about how to accomplish this.)